# Absent / unavailability periods in ScholarOne and other platforms. When are these options useful?

Tags: journals, paper-submission

Submission systems like ScholarOne or Editorial Manager have options where one can indicate absence / unavailability periods. In what context are these options useful and do you make use of them?

Answer (score 1):

In all cases I'm familiar with, this is used to indicate periods when you're unavailable to referee papers. APS' system asks you to state a reason, and lists a number of examples, which give an idea of when the feature can be useful:

> traveling, vacation, overburdened with administrative duties, editor of another journal, retired, switched career, etc.

I would add medical reasons and intense job search periods to that list. In short, you can report unavailability if there is a period during which you don't want to be distracted by the publisher sending review requests, or if you won't be responsive to emails.
I have made use of these systems when I've had periods several months long (may depend on the field and the frequency at which you receive review invitations) during which I'd prefer not getting the emails in the first place over having to repeatedly decline invitations.
In practice, sometimes editors will still contact you through editorial systems you indicated unavailability in, apologetically asking if you can review a resubmission of a paper you refereed in an earlier round, which typically is much less work than reviewing a paper de nouveau.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there also a benefit for authors?

Comment: @Dr.M I've never seen these features used for authors to declare when they're available to handle resubmissions, etc., if that is what you're asking. Journals send their decisions when they're ready. But if editors manage to avoid inviting some potential referees who'd decline or be unresponsive, it can help speed up the review process, at least on average.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use them as it would just add to my administrative task for no personal benefit, and I'd have to do it for each and every platform that might contact me. However, I do use automatic responses to emails (including invitations for review and reminders about them), when I am absent for a while. However, journals/publishers often send invitations from no-reply accounts, and thus never see my note of absence...

Not sure I should be the one in this case that helps them to figure out when I am not around..